# Reshape data from wide to long?

Tags: r

How do I reshape this wide data: (from a csv file)

```
Name    Code    Indicator     1960    1961    1962
```

Into this long format?

```
Name    Code    Indicator     Year
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `reshape2` package does this nicely with the function `melt`.

```
yourdata_melted <- melt(yourdata, id.vars=c('Name', 'Code', 'Indicator'), variable.name='Year')
```

This will add a column of `value` that you can drop. `yourdata_melted$value <- NULL`

Answer (score 5):

And just because I like to continue my campaign for using base R functions:

Test data:

```
test <- data.frame(matrix(1:12,nrow=2))
names(test) <- c("name","code","indicator","1960","1961","1962")
test

  name code indicator 1960 1961 1962
1    1    3         5    7    9   11
2    2    4         6    8   10   12
```

Now reshape it!

```
reshape(
   test,
   idvar=c("name","code","indicator"),
   varying=c("1960","1961","1962"),
   timevar="year",
   v.names="value",
   times=c("1960","1961","1962"),
   direction="long"
)

#           name code indicator year value
#1.3.5.1960    1    3         5 1960     7
#2.4.6.1960    2    4         6 1960     8
#1.3.5.1961    1    3         5 1961     9
#2.4.6.1961    2    4         6 1961    10
#1.3.5.1962    1    3         5 1962    11
#2.4.6.1962    2    4         6 1962    12
```

Comment: I also try to campaign for base R `reshape`--its fast and not too difficult to use after you've used it a few times--but it seems like the functions in the "reshape2" package are the only ones that get any love.

Comment: Plus 1 for the sheer lol of going to the effort just to campaign for base R functions.

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyr`

```
gather(test, "time", "value", 4:6)
```

**Data**

```
test <- data.frame(matrix(1:12,nrow=2))
names(test) <- c("name","code","indicator","1960","1961","1962")
```